# how do you call R scripts via ajax in IIS server

Tags: ajax, r

I am running jquery ajax call to php file to get data and display the data in highcharts. What I would like to do is do my data analysis in R and call the r script to get the data to highcharts.

Is it possible to call R scripts via ajax on windows IIS?

Comment: My guess is that you will probably want your PHP script to shell out and execute an R script.  See http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php.

Comment: @Amit Kumar Gupta, I'll try that tomorrow.

Comment: I may as well make it an answer.

Comment: Hey user14719809.... Can you post a example link for this i also want to run R script SNA function through PHP... Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server-side PHP script should shell out and execute the desired R script.  See http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php for information on shelling out from a PHP script.

Comment: Hey Amit.... Can you post a example link for this i also want to run R script SNA function through PHP... Thanks